# How can write out my dataframe as one file per value of a given column?

Tags: pandas, dask

I have a dataframe with a column called `key` with values ranging from `00` to `FF` (as strings). Ideally I would write that dataframe as parquet as one or more files per value of `key`. That is, I don't want a partition to have more that one possible value for `key`.

My current approach is not working, as it produces a single file:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = dd.read_csv(
        "/Users/ecerulm/Downloads/test/**/*.txt.gz",
        include_path_column=True,
        sep="\t",
        compression='gzip',
        blocksize=None)
df['basename'] = (df.path.str.rpartition('/')[2])
df['MAC'] = df.basename.str.partition('.')[2]
df['MAC'] = df.MAC.str.partition('.')[0]
df['key'] = df.MAC.str[-2:]
df = df.set_index('key')
df = df.repartition(partition_size='100MB')
df = df.shuffle(['key'])

dd.to_parquet(df, './output.parquet')
```

Is there any way to ensure that the partitions are "cleanly" partitioned on a column (I thought that [df.shuffle()](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.Series.shuffle) would do that but it seems does not guarantee that each partition will only contain a single value of the `on` columns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the specific case of outputting Parquet you can just use `df.to_parquet(...,partition_on=['column_name'])`.

```
df.read_csv(...)
#df.set_index('key')
#df.repartition(partition_size='100MB')
#df.shuffle(['key'])
dd.to_parquet(df, '.output.parquet', partition_on=['key'])
```

That will produce:

```
output.parquet/key=00/part.0.parquet
output.parquet/key=00/...
output.parquet/key=00/part.3.parquet
...
output.parquet/key=FF/part.13.parquet
```

So it will guarantee that each value of `key` will be confined to a single directory. If you want to minimize the number of `part.x.parquet` files on each directory you can add `df.repartition()` before the `to_parquet`

```
df = df.repartition(partition_size='100MB')
dd.to_parquet(df, './output.parquet', partition_on=['key'])
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the existing answer, you can achieve a single file per unique value of the `key` column by setting the index to the `key` column and setting the `divisions` to follow the unique values in that column. Note that `set_index` is an expensive operation and depending on your use case you may be better off with the 'many small files in a single directory' solution proposed above using `partition_on`.

Using `set_index` and `divisions`:

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create dummy dataset with 3 partitions
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"letter": ["a", "b", "c", "a", "a", "d", "d", "b", "c", "b", "a", "b", "c", "e", "e", "e"], "number": np.arange(0,16)}
)

ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=3)

# set index to column of interest
ddf = ddf.set_index('letter').persist()

# generate list of divisions (last value needs to be repeated)
index_values = list(df.letter.unique())
divisions = index_values.append(df.letter.unique()[-1])

# repartition 
ddf = ddf.repartition(divisions=divisions).persist()

# write out partitions as separate parquet files
for i in range(ddf.npartitions):
    ddf.partitions[i].to_parquet(f"file_{i}.parquet", engine='pyarrow')
```

As per [the Dask docs](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-design.html#partitions): "Divisions includes the minimum value of every partition’s index and the maximum value of the last partition’s index." This means the last value needs to be included twice since it serves as both the start of and the end of the last partition's index.